# A small set numerical puzzle

Tags: mathematics, pattern, number-sequence

Three, 
Twenty-one, 
and forty-five

start  
this list 
that has arrived.

<sub>---edit for a little more clarity---</sub>

Ninety-one 
and one hundred and twenty. 
Then we get to the doubly interesting number.

After which 
comes two hundred and ten. 
Three hundred and naught ends this list of wonder. 
<sub>---end of edit---</sub>

Only  
eight numbers  
exist in this little set.

A  
small pattern,  
but one I hope you will get.

What  
goes unnamed 
here in my little list?

Why is  
it interesting? 
What gives it the twist?

If you 
can solve my rhyme,  
you'll feel rather quite peachy.

Can 
you say 
veni vidi vici?

My second finite list 
only numbers but three. 
Unfair on it's own, 
a companion it'll be.

<sub>----second edit to improve readability----</sub>
Start at forty nine;
then sixty plus four.
One hundred twenty one;
there is no more.
<sub>----end of edit----</sub>

Also twice as special 
is one of these 
Can you tell why 
and which one, please?

---

Edit for hints:

Hint 1

> was going to be to point out the structure of my poem.  But, since this hint is supposed to lead a reader to Dmihawk's conclusion, it hardly counts as a hint anymore.

Hint 2

> There is a particular phrase that I hoped would stand out.  While the phrase itself gives no direct hint as to the riddle, it does suggest (I hope) something to do with the set items.

---

----First Edit----

Edited to make it more obvious that there is a missing number in the first sequence.

original lines before edit:

Ninety-one 
and one hundred and twenty 
take us to the doubly interesting number.

Two hundred and ten 
followed by (and ending with) three hundred 
give us the final integers in this finite list of wonder.

----original lines before second edit to improve readability----
Four more than sixty,  
and fifty minus one, 
one hundred twenty one 
and this list's done.

Comment: Is the order in which the second list is presented significant, and are we intended to assume that the first list is in strictly ascending order (so 120<x<210)?

Comment: @Zomulgustar fair questions.  Yes to the first list (and the unknown number's value), no to the second.  I used that order strictly to make the stanzas in the second part all the same length.  That is an area of the riddle I wouldn't mind editing for clarity &/or would be happy to have editing suggestions.

Comment: Perhaps you could make that stanza ABAB by rhyming sixty-and-four with some variation off 'isn't any more'?

Comment: @Zomulgustar Let's see if that looks better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The missing number from the first set is

> 190

because the set consists of

> those **tri**angular numbers which when written as Roman numerals have length **three**.

The second set consists of

> those s**qua**res which when written as Roman numerals have length **four**.

It is not yet apparent to me why the doubly-special ones are so. The obvious ways in this context to be twice as interesting would be

> either to have *another* notable representation of length 3 (resp. 4), or (less plausibly) to be another kind of k-gonal number with some other representation of length k. Well, 190 has length 3 in *our* number system, but so do e.g. 120 and 300, so that's clearly not it. 190 is a hexagonal as well as a triangular number (as are half of all triangular numbers) but again so are 120 and 300. 190 is also the product of exactly three primes, but none of our squares is the product of exactly four primes.

Obviously

> the layout of the lines gestures towards the triangularity/squareness of the numbers they describe

and

> "veni vidi vici" is directing us toward Roman numerals.

Comment: Excellent! I'm tempted to give you the green check, because you got the unknown number and what makes these sets finite, and given that I didn't really explain why the doubly interesting numbers would be doubly interesting. You are on the right track with your thinking.  I'll see if I can think up a stanza that hints at the doubly interesting numbers without giving away the answers.

Comment: If I'm on the right track then maybe 64 is the doubly-special number from the second set. Of course I have one chance in 3 of guessing that even with no correct ideas of what's going on...

Comment: After some time, I've realized I don't know that I'll be able to write a new stanza that doesn't make it obvious, hence Gareth gets the tick.  (I was thinking of adding a fourth square stanza, if anyone wants to give it a try.)  The doubly interesting numbers were so because there indices are also written as 3 or 4 character roman numerals.  Looking back on it, maybe not that interesting.

Comment: Ah! I don't think I'd ever have got that.

Answer (score 1):

**Partial Answer**

Not sure if it's relevant, but...

The first sequence

> are all triangular numbers

The second sequence

> are all square numbers

Comment: Right track.  But why these finite subsets?